# How to handle exception for mysql sleep queries in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using below sleep mysql query in PHP.

```
select sleep(50);
```

It takes 50 seconds to complete. PHP page is lading till that 50 seconds. Here I want to throw exception in PHP page. How can be achieved this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set_time_limit(30)` if you want to stop the script after 30 seconds and you can use `register_shutdown_function()` to handle the script exiting because of time expiration:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(30);
$script_finished = false;
register_shutdown_function('is_finished');
function is_finished(){
global $script_finished;
if(!$script_finished){
//Script got interrupted 
echo "Oh, this script takes too much to complete!";
}
}
//Your code here
//...
//...
sleep(50); //For example

//Right before ending of php tag, script has ended
//Don't through is_finished function
$script_finished = true;
?>
```

Comment: Script is not stopping after 30 seconds. its still loading 50 seconds.

Comment: I am using mysqli_query($link, "select sleep(50)");

Comment: Franz, any solution?

Comment: That code might help you handle the exceeding... You need to set a max time also on MySQL side http://mysqlserverteam.com/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/